# ConstraintLayout ConstraintSet applies instantly instead of animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- ... -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fieldView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topLayout" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fieldView">

    <!-- ... -->
```

I want `actionsLayout` to slide from bottom of screen (from out-of-screen in fact) to the bottom of `fieldView`.

```
    ConstraintSet()
            .apply {
                clone(context, R.layout.fragment_problem)

                connect(R.id.actionsLayout, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.fieldView, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
            }
            .runAnimation(rootLayout, actionsLayoutAppearAnimationDuration, OvershootInterpolator())
```

`runAnimation` source:

```
fun ConstraintSet.runAnimation(rootLayout: ConstraintLayout, duration: Long, interpolator: Interpolator = LinearInterpolator()) {
    val transition = AutoTransition()
        .apply {
            this.duration = duration
            this.interpolator = interpolator
        }

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, transition)
    this.applyTo(rootLayout)
}
```

*Note: this extension function works fine on other layouts.*

But on this layout and this animation it does not animate constraints change, but instead just instantly applies it. So, layout looks just like I expect, except animation — there is just no animation at all. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks that starting animation in `onViewCreated` is not the best idea. The easiest solution is to call it in `rootLayout.post()`.